cannot use react-input-mask with typescript

No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Props):
ReactInputMask', gave the following error.
Type '(inputProps: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactI18NextChildren | Iterable'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Props, context: any): ReactInputMask', gave
the following error.
Type '(inputProps: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactI18NextChildren | Iterable'.ts(2769)

There is no exported type for ReactI18NextChildren. It seems like coming from i18 library but why there is no connection between them.
"react-input-mask": "2.0.4",
"@types/react-input-mask": "2.0.4",

<Controller
  name="cardNumber"
  control={control}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <InputMask mask="9999 9999 9999 9999" {...field}>
      {(inputProps: Props) => <TextField {...inputProps} variant="standard" fullWidth />}
    </InputMask>
  )}
/>


I  had the same issue and couldn't find a resolution with that package. It turns out that package has been abandoned and someone else forked it and maintains it now. The current fork is like 56 commits ahead. I switched to the fork and it's working for me now.
https://github.com/mona-health/react-input-mask
Additionally, I think they changed it so that the child isn't a function anymore. You can remove {(inputProps: Props) =>
